# Python Google translate error while translating text, ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443)

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api

I want to convert bunch of sentences from Vietnamese to English saved in excel file. I have around 200 sentences. I have latest version of `urllib3`. Even if I keep just 10 sentences and run a code below I get following error. Is there any limit to number of sentences I can translate at a time?

**Error:**

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

**Code:**

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import math
translator = Translator()

data=pd.read_excel('C:\TextAnalytics\Vietnamese to english.xlsx',dtype=object)


data.to_csv('data_temp.csv')

unique_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Subreason'].value_counts()).reset_index()[['index']]

unique_data['Translations']=''

for i in range(len(unique_data)):
    temp=(unique_data['index'].iloc[i])
    if(type(temp)==str):
        print(temp)
        a=translator.translate(temp,src='vi',dest='en')
        unique_data['Translations'].iloc[i]=a.text
        print(a.text)
        if(i%20==0):
            time.sleep(5)
            print(i)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

        if(i>20000):
            break

translate_dict=unique_data.set_index('index').to_dict().get('Translations')

data['Google_Translate']=data.REWORK_DESCRIPTION.map(translate_dict)

data.drop('Converted',inplace=True,axis=1)

path=r'data mv table.xls'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
data.to_excel(writer, 'Translated', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: which library are you using? it doesn't seems the latest Translate API version. check this link: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python And also this is the last API version: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/translate

Comment: @AlexRiquelme: I am using `googletrans`. Is it mandatory to create billing account to use Google Translate API. I am new to this Google Translate API.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that, I don't know anything about "googletrans"